# How to handle JavaFX launcher error?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application that use external library in folder lib . If the library is not exist it will cause javafx launcher error : Exception while running application and program is closed. I want to give message on my own that the library is missing  before program closed. How to give that message before the program closed ?

Comment: can you give me the example code for catch exception javafx launcher error ?

Comment: Try to cover your code with try..catch(Exception e). This will lead to capture all the possible exceptions ! You can print your message in the catch block ! You may also catch specific exceptions, if you are aware of them !

Answer (score 0):

The message "Error while running application" can be displayed due to a variety of reasons, as far as I know there is not a unique way to deal with it. It depends on the context, and the actual `Exception` thrown. Have a look at your stack trace for more details, you should be able to identify the `Exception` that's causing the issue.

If you are using `System.loadLibrary` to load your library, then the Exception to catch is probably `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using javafx 8 or later you can register your own `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to handle any unexpected behaviour of your application and register it (in log or on UI if possible).

Example:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception was caught in thread: '{}' with message: '{}'",
                thread.getName(), throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
    }

}
```

Place it as close to start or your application as possible.